# jquery how clone bootstrap row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone a bootstrap row but every time I get a multiple-line (1-2-4-8-etc)

```
$("#clone").click(function() {
    $(".cloned-row:first").clone().insertAfter(".cloned-row");
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="cloned-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="foo">Foo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="foo[]" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="bar">bar</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bar[]" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="button" class="form-control btn-info" value="clone" id="clone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="button" class="form-control btn-danger" value="remove" id="remove">
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I do to clone only a div cloned-row at a time?
Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are simply telling it to insert after *every* cloned row with `insertAfter(".cloned-row")`. That is causing additional cloning you did not expect.

Just insert after the last one using `:last`

e.g.

```
insertAfter(".cloned-row:last")
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/u8zdutfy/