# jQuery weird Bootstrap row cloning behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My objective is to do cloning on the bootstrap row in my form to collect inputs from user. Basically it is exactly the same thing like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175841/jquery-how-clone-bootstrap-row). However for some reason, I am experiencing weird behaviour of cloning and I am really baffled me for some times now.

This is the DOM that I have:

```
<div class="cloned-row">
    <div class="row" id="row_1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                // some inputs here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row_2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                // some inputs here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am cloning the list child of `.cloned-row` (which in this case the row with id `row_2`) and want to make it as third row. (I will also change the id after the row is cloned but that will be later, as I am still experiencing problem with the clone) But for some reason, my clone jQuery code clones both row. So after the clone it becomes 4 rows. Below is my jQuery clone part:

```
$(document).on('click', '#plus_now', function(){
    $(".cloned-row:last").clone().insertAfter(".cloned-row:last");
});
```

Looking for guidance from somebody on this. This is totally unexpected. Appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're cloning the whole `.cloned-row` element -- try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#plus_now', function(){
    $(".cloned-row .row:last-child").clone().insertAfter(".cloned-row .row:last-child");
});
```

To clone just the last `.row` element

Comment: There's no :last-child in jquery. https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: @Banzay I thought :last-child does exists? https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: This one works for me. I'll go with this. Thanks mate!

Comment: "While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more than one: one for each parent."

Answer (score 2):

You're cloning the last `.cloned-row` (see https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/). Try

```
$(document).on('click', '#plus_now', function(){
    $(".row:last").clone().insertAfter(".row:last");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. +1. Your solution works perfectly. But I do prefer to mention the class `.cloned-row` to avoid conflict with other DOMs. Thanks again.